# Help navigating an XML file with multiple namespaces using simplexml

Tags: php, xml, simplexml, xml-namespaces

I am working on a program to collect meteorological data from an XML file. In particular I would like to navigate through a file such as the one referenced below and pull out wind statistics for specific locations.

Locations are identified in the metadata of the Observation tag in the element with name="station_name". The wind data is contained in Observation -> elements.

The use of multiple namespaces seems to be stymying my limited knowledge of how to use simplexml to parse an xml file.

An xml file I am trying to parse is: http://dd.weatheroffice.gc.ca/observations/xml/MB/hourly/hourly_mb_2011050723_e.xml

I have cut this down for testing to one observation (per below):

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <om:ObservationCollection xmlns:om="http://www.opengis.net/om/1.0" xmlns="http://dms.ec.gc.ca/schema/point-observation/2.0" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<om:member>
    <om:Observation>
        <om:metadata>
            <set><general><author name="MSC-DMS-PG-WXO-HOURLY" version="1.5"/><dataset name="msc/observation/atmospheric/surface_weather/wxo-2.0-ascii"/><phase name="product-hourly_en-xml-2.0"/><id xlink:href="/data/msc/observation/atmospheric/surface_weather/wxo-2.0-ascii/product-hourly_en-xml-2.0/201105072356/mb"/><parent xlink:href="/data/msc/observation/atmospheric/surface_weather/cs-1.0-binary/decoded-xml-2.0/201105072300/cpgh"/></general>
            <identification-elements>
                <element name="station_name" uom="unitless" value="Gimli"/>
                <element name="latitude" uom="degree" value="50.63"/>
                <element name="longitude" uom="degree" value="-97.05"/>
                <element name="transport_canada_id" uom="unitless" value="PGH"/>
                <element name="observation_date_utc" uom="unitless" value="2011-05-07T23:00:00.000Z"/>
                <element name="observation_date_local_time" uom="unitless" value="2011-05-07T18:00:00.000 CDT"/>
                <element name="climate_station_number" uom="unitless" value="5031042"/>
                <element name="wmo_station_number" uom="unitless" value="71748"/>
            </identification-elements>
            </set>
        </om:metadata>
        <om:samplingTime><gml:TimeInstant><gml:timePosition>2011-05-07T23:00:00.000Z</gml:timePosition></gml:TimeInstant></om:samplingTime>
        <om:resultTime><gml:TimeInstant><gml:timePosition>2011-05-07T23:56:09.099Z</gml:timePosition></gml:TimeInstant></om:resultTime>
        <om:procedure xlink:href=""/>
        <om:observedProperty gml:remoteSchema="/schema/point-observation/2.0.xsd"/>
        <om:featureOfInterest>
            <gml:FeatureCollection>
                <gml:location><gml:Point><gml:pos>50.63333333333333 -97.05</gml:pos></gml:Point></gml:location>
            </gml:FeatureCollection>
        </om:featureOfInterest>
        <om:result>
        <orig-header/>
        <elements>
            <element name="present_weather" uom="code" value=""/>
            <element name="mean_sea_level" uom="kPa" value="100.89"/>
            <element name="tendency_amount" uom="kPa" value="0.07"/>
            <element name="tendency_characteristic" uom="code" value="rising"/>
            <element name="horizontal_visibility" uom="km" value=""/>
            <element name="air_temperature" uom="Celsius" value="11.4"/>
            <element name="dew_point" uom="Celsius" value="8.2"/>
            <element name="relative_humidity" uom="percent" value="81.0"/>
            <element name="wind_speed" uom="km/h" value="24.8"/>
            <element name="wind_direction" uom="code" value="SW"/>
            <element name="wind_gust_speed" uom="km/h" value="36.4"/>
            <element name="total_cloud_cover" uom="code" value=""/>
            <element name="wind_chill" uom="unitless" value=""/>
            <element name="humidex" uom="unitless" value=""/>
        </elements>
        </om:result>
    </om:Observation>
</om:member>
    </om:ObservationCollection>
```

This is what I have so far, and it is officially getting me nowhere...

```
    <?php
$xml = simplexml_load_file("weather.xml");
foreach($xml->item as $item){
    $collection = $item->children("http://www.opengis.net/om/1.0");
}

print_r($collection->member);

    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using [XPath](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/) language to query for your data with [xpath](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.xpath.php) method from SimpleXMLElement.

Comment: Ok, I've tried using xpath, but it doesn't seem to be getting me anywhere. I've got the following code: `$xml = simplexml_load_file("weather.xml");
 $xml->registerXPathNamespace("om", "http://www.opengis.net/om/1.0");
 $elements = $xml->xpath("//om:Observation");
 
 $location = $xml->xpath("/om:ObservationCollection/om:member/om:Observation/om:metadata");

 $test[0] = $location->xpath("/set");
 
 foreach($test as $k=>$v){
  echo "<br/>$k=$v";
 }` which is at least giving me an array for $elements, but I'm not getting anything out of $test.

Comment: "/set" means "set" from root of the document, try using "./set" or even just "set" as your xpath. also why do you assign result to $test[0], why not just $test?

Comment: No good reason for $test[0], I believe that is a remnant of when I assumed that $test was returning an array. When I do $location->xpath("./set") I get this error : Fatal error: Call to a member function xpath() on a non-object in simple_xml.php on line 9. If I do $xml->xpath("./set") nothing is output to the page. What code would you use to return the value attribute of <element name="station_name" uom="unitless" value="Gimli"/> from the xml file?

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately I've used str_replace to replace the om: in the original xml string. This negated the need to apply the name space, and made it simple to navigate the xml using simplexml.

Comment: Ironic! When I fetch data from web services, like a last.fm script I wrote the other week, I always use a regex to *add* a temporary namespace to the root node if it doesn't have one, so that I can distinguish the elements easily when I merge the documents and use XSLT.